# how to make a macro script to delete all strings \answer{*}

Tags: macros

how to make a macro script to delete all strings `\answer{*}`. For example:

```
\begin{problem}
    question 1: what day is it today?
    \answer{
    To day is \textbf{Monday}.
    }
\end{problem}


\begin{problem}
    question 2: what day is it today?
    \answer{
        To day is \textbf{Tuesday}.
    }
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    question 3: what day is it today?
    \answer{
        To day is \textbf{Wednesday}.
    }
\end{problem}
```

the result is:

```
\begin{problem}
    question 1: what day is it today?
\end{problem}


\begin{problem}
    question 2: what day is it today?
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    question 3: what day is it today?
\end{problem}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\answer}[1]{}`?

Comment: thank you. But I want to clear  all \answer{*}.

Comment: That's what that command will do. Just put it before the first use of `\answer` in your document.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want the tex *source* to look like your result, or if you want the resulting pdf to look *as if* you had that source.

Comment: TeX usually leaves your `.tex` file (the input) unchanged, so if you wanted to remove the `\answer`s physically TeX itself would not be the right tool. (Usually I would recommend RegExp searches, but those will probably have a hard time here, because RegExp is not very good at tracking matching braces/TeX grouping.) In this case it should be possible to achieve the same effect as physically removing `\answer` from the input by redefining the `\answer` macro within TeX. This is what cfr suggests. How exactly that needs to happen may depend on the exact implementation of `problem` and `\answer`.